# Thoughts on improving the existing aggregate pyspark code

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

Here is a spark dataframe i have,

```
+---+----------------------------------+----------+----------+
|id |timestamp                         |Fname     |Lname     |
+---+----------------------------------+----------+----------+
|1  |2024-01-19T11:52:44.775205Z       |Robert    |Albert    |
|1  |2024-01-20T11:52:44.775205Z       |Remo      |Lergos    |
|2  |2024-01-21T11:52:44.775205Z       |Charlie   |Jameson   |
|2  |2024-01-22T11:52:44.775205Z       |Anastacio |Sporer    |
|2  |2024-01-23T11:52:44.775205Z       |Luz       |Toy       |
|3  |2024-01-24T11:52:44.775205Z       |Crystal   |Hills     |
|3  |2024-01-25T11:52:44.775205Z       |Nicholas  |Johnson   |
+---+----------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

Below are the steps involved,

1. Group by the "id" vales
2. Get the first name and latest name as list of dictionaries.
3. Based on the most recent timestamp for the "id" get the fname and Lname and store them as a seperate column as a dictionary.
4. The most recent timestamp used in step3 should also be stored as seperate column.

Based on the above steps I am trying to get to the resultant dataframe as below,

```
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id  |latest_names                          |latest_timestamp            |all_names                                                                                            |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"}     |2024-01-20T11:52:44.775205Z |[{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"},{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"}]                                |
|2   |{"Fname":"Luz","Lname":"Toy"}         |2024-01-23T11:52:44.775205Z |[{"Fname":"Luz","Lname":"Toy"},{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"},{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"}]  |     
|3   |{"Fname":"Nicholas","Lname":"Johnson"}|2024-01-25T11:52:44.775205Z |[{"Fname":"Nicholas","Lname":"Johnson"},{"Fname":"Remo","Lname":"Lergos"}]                           |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried the following pyspark code with join and a windowspec to get the first elements with desc of timestamp,

```
windowspec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(df["timestamp"].desc())
columns_names = ["Fname","Lname"]
df.withColumn(
    "all_names",
    F.to_json(
        F.struct(
            "Fname","Lname"
        )
    ),
)
.withColumn(
    "latest_names",
    F.to_json(
        F.struct(*[F.first(field).over(windowspec).alias(field) for field in columns_names])
    ),
)
.withColumn("latest_timestamp", F.first("timestamp").over(windowspec).alias("timestamp"))
.groupBy("id")
.agg(
    F.collect_set("all_names").alias("all_names"),
    F.first("latest_names").alias("latest_names"),
    F.first("l_timestamp").alias("latest_timestamp"),
)
```

Iam able to acheive the result but would like to know if there is a better of doing this as i have multiple columns to perform a similar operation of (Fname,Lname)
i have other columns (address1,address2,address3) where i want to perform the same column operation to get the latest address, i was using a single windowspec for that operation butis there a better way of doing this ???

Comment: if you aggregate by ID, and collect the 3 other columns as a struct in a list, you can then process that one column and extract the "first" data you need, without any further aggregation. Using simple functions like sort array, and getItem. These functions do not requires aggregation so the process should be simpler

Comment: Can you share a code snippet for doing so?

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) first.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and let me know what you think:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.struct('timestamp', 'Fname', 'Lname')).alias('all_names'),
        f.max('timestamp').alias('latest_timestamp')
    )
    .withColumn('latest_name', f.expr("filter(all_names, x -> x.timestamp = latest_timestamp)")[0])
    .select(
        'id',
        f.expr('transform(all_names, x -> struct(x.Fname, x.Lname))').alias('all_names'), 
        'latest_timestamp',
        f.struct('latest_name.Fname', 'latest_name.Lname').alias('latest_name'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this is simpler but i also want to remove duplicates in this case and adding an additional field `timestamp` field makes it very complicated, is there a way around to deal with that?

Comment: @Jack109 I have revised the solution. Check it out.